# Can IntelliJ IDEA open more than one editor window for files from the same project?

Tags: java, ide, intellij-idea

I can split editor panes horizontally or vertically, but it does not seem possible to view code in two separate physical windows.  I am aware that Idea can open multiple **projects** in separate windows, but I'd like to be able to do this for two files in a **single** project.

One answer suggested unpinning the tab, but I haven't been able to make that work (I'm on Mac OSX if that matters.)

This seems like a basic feature in today's world of multi-headed workstations.  Before moving to an IDE I used to do this regularly with good old Emacs.  Is there some trick I am not aware of to make this happen?

Comment: It seems that this is not possible.  Are there any Intellij folks on StackOverflow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way (as of IDEA 8.0.1) to do what you're asking for. As you pointed out, you can split the editor pane but there is always exactly one editor per IDEA project.

UPDATE: As of IDEA 10 (currently the latest is 10.5), the answer is yes, you can :-)

Comment: It's not the answer I want.  But it seems to be the correct answer.  :-[

Answer (score 8):

This is now possible in IDEA X. Hopefully you're still an IDEA user and can take advantage of this :)

Comment: Just tried it, and it worked: drag a tab off the window, drop, another editor window opens.

Answer (score 1):

I work around the limitation by opening one source file in vi, on a second head monitor.
Then work main file within Idea (actually Pycharm).

Update: even with the feature built into pycharm, I still use vi.  Works better.

Answer (score 0):

As per @9000's comment, an editor tab can be turned into a new window by dragging the tab outside of IDEA.

Answer (score -1):

Yes- with [IDEA X](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/training/demos/detachable_tabs/index.html), it is finally possible to open multiple editor windows.